# Adding multiple bokeh html files to a django template

Tags: python, django, bokeh

I created some plots with bokeh and exported them as html files. I now try to add these plots in a django template. The first plot works just fine, but if I want to add a second one it is not displayed.

Here i have the python file that creates the bokeh html:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("test2.html",title="test2")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.circle([1, 5, 7, 2, 5], [6, 7, 2, 5, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```

This is the second plot, the first one is saved as test.html, the title is test and some of the point coordinates are different.

And here is my django template:

```
{% extends "MainPage/PageBase.html" %}
{% block content %} 
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <font size="3">plot1</font>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                    <p><div class="basic">

                        {% include "GPanalysis\WorkingData\test.html" %}

                    </div></p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <font size="3">plot2</font>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                    <p><div class="basic">

                        {% include "GPanalysis\WorkingData\test2.html" %}

                    </div></p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In the first box appears a graph but the second one is empty.

I switched the position of two plots, but only the one that comes first in the html script will be displayed. If I try to call the same graph twice, it will be plotted twice but the second one is directly below the first one and not at the location it should be according to the html script.

I am not sure if this is an error i have somewhere or if what I am trying is simply not possible. I am aware, that there are other possibilities to get multiple bokeh plots in one template, but this one would be the easyest for my situation as i have to generate the html files anyway.

Thanks for any helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. Bokeh file output is not designed or intended to be embedded this way, and there is no expectation that it should work well or at all:

- File output generates full HTML files with their own `<head>`, by doing this you are 100% guaranteed to generate malformed HTML
- Bokeh objects from different files will probably end up stomping on each other, because file output is not intended to be used this way.

There are APIs sepcifically purposed for [Embedding Plots and Apps](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) and those should be used.